# ¿Como llenar un arreglo respecto a los valores de otro arreglo en javascript?

Tags: javascript, array, object

Me encuentro realizando el algoritmo genético de un rebaño de ovejas.
resulta que de este ejercicio genero una población que serian un array de objetos.

Ejemplo de población, por su puesto para este problema se deben generar mas objetos, pero este utilice una cantidad mínima solo como ejemplo:

```
poblacion: [
  {nombre: "Oveja 1", peso: 147, precio: 4026}
  {nombre: "Oveja 2", peso: 168, precio: 3975}
  {nombre: "Oveja 3", peso: 106, precio: 1642}
  {nombre: "Oveja 4", peso: 145, precio: 3639}
  {nombre: "Oveja 5", peso: 117, precio: 1838}
  {nombre: "Oveja 6", peso: 151, precio: 2355}
]
```

A partir de esta población debo crear otros arreglos cumpliendo la condición que la suma de los valores peso no exceda de 300, siguiendo con este ejemplo los siguientes arreglos deberían quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
camion1: [
    {nombre: "Oveja 1", peso: 147, precio: 4026}
  ]

camion2:[
    {nombre: "Oveja 2", peso: 168, precio: 3975}
    {nombre: "Oveja 3", peso: 106, precio: 1642}
  ]

camion3:[
    {nombre: "Oveja 4", peso: 145, precio: 3639}
    {nombre: "Oveja 5", peso: 117, precio: 1838}
  ]

camion4:[
    {nombre:  "Oveja 6", peso: 151, precio: 2355}
  ]
```

Como veran los arrays camion1, camion2, camion3 y camion4 tienen los objetos del array poblacion con la diferencia que al sumar la propiedad peso no sobrepasa de 300.
¿Como podria crear esos subarrays?, de momento tengo esto:

```
var poblacion = [];
var camion = [];
var objCromosomas = {};

var maxpesoAleatorio = 200;
var minpesoAleatorio = 50;

var maxprecioAleatorio = 5000;
var minprecioAleatorio = 1500;

var pesoCamion = 2000;
var sumaPeso = 0;
var sumapesoIdeal = 0;

for (var i = 1; i<190; i++) {
    var objOveja = new Object();
    var pesoAleatorio = Math.round(Math.random() * (maxpesoAleatorio - minpesoAleatorio) + minpesoAleatorio);
    var precioAleatorio = Math.round(Math.random() * (maxprecioAleatorio - minprecioAleatorio) + minprecioAleatorio);

    objOveja.nombre = "Oveja "+i;
    objOveja.peso   = pesoAleatorio;    
    objOveja.precio = precioAleatorio;
    poblacion.push(objOveja);
}
angular.forEach(poblacion, function(value, key){
    sumaPeso = value.peso+sumaPeso;
    if (sumaPeso < pesoCamion) {
        camion.push(value);
    }
});

 objCromosomas["camion"] = camion;
 console.log(objCromosomas);
```

Al final mi resultado deberia quedar asi:

```
{
 nombre: "Cromosomas",
 camion1: [{},{}],
 camion2: [{},{}]
 ..........
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que esto deberia de servirte:

```
var camionN = 1; /*Para llevar una cuenta de los camiones*/

angular.forEach(poblacion, function(value, key){
    sumaPeso = value.peso+sumaPeso;
    sumaPrecio = value.precio+sumaPrecio
    if (sumaPeso < pesoCamion) {
        camion.push(value);

        /*En caso de que ya se haya recorrido todo el array población*/
        if(value == poblacion[poblacion.length-1]){ 
          objCromosomas["camion"+camionN] = camion;
          objCromosomas["camion"+camionN].total = sumaPrecio;
        }
    }else{ /*Cuando el camion se llene*/

        /*se agrega el array camion a objCromosomas*/ 
        objCromosomas["camion"+camionN] = camion;
        objCromosomas["camion"+camionN].total = sumaPrecio;
        camionN++;  

        camion = []; //vacío el camión para comenzar a llenarlo de nuevo
        //meto a la oveja que no cabía en el camión anterior
        camion.push(value);
        sumaPeso = value.peso;
        sumaPrecio = value.precio;
    }
});
```

Y el código completo sería asi

```
var poblacion = [];
var camion = [];
var objCromosomas = {};

var maxpesoAleatorio = 200;
var minpesoAleatorio = 50;

var maxprecioAleatorio = 5000;
var minprecioAleatorio = 1500;

var pesoCamion = 2000;
var sumaPeso = 0;
var sumaPrecio = 0;
var sumapesoIdeal = 0;

for (var i = 1; i<190; i++) {
    var objOveja = new Object();
    var pesoAleatorio = Math.round(Math.random() * (maxpesoAleatorio - 
    minpesoAleatorio) + minpesoAleatorio);
    var precioAleatorio = Math.round(Math.random() * (maxprecioAleatorio - 
    minprecioAleatorio) + minprecioAleatorio);

    objOveja.nombre = "Oveja "+i;
    objOveja.peso   = pesoAleatorio;    
    objOveja.precio = precioAleatorio;
    poblacion.push(objOveja);
}

var camionN = 1; /*Para llevar una cuenta de los camiones*/

angular.forEach(poblacion, function(value, key){
    sumaPeso = value.peso+sumaPeso;
    sumaPrecio = value.precio+sumaPrecio
    if (sumaPeso < pesoCamion) {
        camion.push(value);

        /*En caso de que ya se haya recorrido todo el array población*/
        if(value == poblacion[poblacion.length-1]){ 
          objCromosomas["camion"+camionN] = camion;
          objCromosomas["camion"+camionN].total = sumaPrecio;
        }
    }else{ /*Cuando el camion se llene*/

        /*se agrega el array camion a objCromosomas*/ 
        objCromosomas["camion"+camionN] = camion;
        objCromosomas["camion"+camionN].total = sumaPrecio;
        camionN++;  

        camion = []; //vacío el camión para comenzar a llenarlo de nuevo
        //meto a la oveja que no cabia en el camión anterior
        camion.push(value);
        sumaPeso = value.peso;  
        sumaPrecio = value.precio;
    }
});

console.log(objCromosomas);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me ha ayudado, solo ando haciendo pruebas y he notando que cuando en la poblacion la genero con el ciclo for i<30, poblacion se crea entonces con 29 objetos, pero el array de camion1 con 16 objetos dejando en el aire a 12 objetos que ya no entran a ningun nuevo array.

Comment: excelente, muchísimas gracias.

Comment: Buena tarde, sera que podrías ayudarme, necesito obtener el precio total por cada camión que se genere, ¿como seria?.

Comment: estaria bien que dentro del array camion exista un objeto con el total del precio del camion.
Desde ya te agradezco.

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias Ramirez. Bendiciones.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que podrias crear un array de arrays asi:

```
var camiones = [];
angular.forEach(poblacion, function(value, key){
    sumaPeso = value.peso+sumaPeso;

    if (sumaPeso < pesoCamion) {
        camion.push(value);
    } else {
        camiones.push(camion);
        camion = [];
        camion.push(value);
        sumaPeso = value.peso;
    }
});
```